# It keeps returning with errors when I try to do '.author'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Heres the beginning of the command

```
@client.command()
async def rps(ctx, *, message):
    ai_choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    ai_choice = random.choice(ai_choices)

    message.lower()
```

Heres the logic statements

```
    if ai_choice == message:
        ctx.send(f'{message.author}, you played {message}, and Miska played {ai_choice}, so {message.author}it\'s a tie!')
    elif ai_choice == 'rock' and message == 'paper':
        ctx.send(f'{message.author}, you played paper, Miska played rock, so {message.author} YOU WIN!!')
    elif ai_choice == 'paper' and message == 'scissors':
        ctx.send(f'{message.author}, you played paper, Miska played rock, so {message.author} YOU WIN!!')
    elif ai_choice == 'scissors' and message == 'rock':
        ctx.send(f'{message.author}, you played rock, Miska played scissors, so {message.author} YOU WIN!!')
    elif ai_choice == 'rock' and message == 'scissors':
        ctx.send(f'{message.author}, you played scissors, Miska played rock, so MISKA WINS')
    elif ai_choice == 'paper' and message == 'rock':
        ctx.send(f'{message.author}, you played rock, Miska played paper, so MISKA WINS')
    elif ai.choice == 'scissors' and message == 'paper':
        ctx.send(f'{message.author}, you played paper, Miska played scissors, so MISKA WINS')
    else:
        ctx.send('Miska says, "You entered an invalid input please try entering ROCK, PAPER, or SCISSORS"')
```

Heres the error log with the hard drive path omitted

```
Ignoring exception in command rps:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 61, in rps
    ctx.send(f'{message.author}, you played {message}, and Miska played {ai_choice}, so {message.author}it\'s a tie!')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Also I couldnt think of a better way to make my code more efficient for all of the if, elifs, and elses so if you any way on helping that be more efficient let me know since im very new to programming.

Comment: `message` is one of the strings `rock`, `paper`, or `scissors`. What is `message.author` supposed to be?

Comment: `message.lower()` doesn't do anything. I think you mean `message = message.lower()`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the argument `message` is actually a string, hence the error says `'str' object has no attribute 'author'`.

Get the message's author's name through your context argument.
`ctx.message.author.name`.